# Using Dynamic Paint To Spawn Particles Through Vertex Groups

Tags: particles, vertex-groups, dynamic-paint

What is causing the particle system to not follow the density group? Use modifier stack is enabled, both objects are well subdivided and the canvas object is an unmodified plane.

[image]

Comment: The emission is not keyframeable, one of the many shortcomings of the particle systems they promised to fix since 2015. Depending on what you want to achieve there are workarounds, I don't want to post any answers, though, because I would probably get downvoted. They are kind of hacky.

Comment: appricate the answer nonetheless, what I'm trying to accomplish is basically this https://youtu.be/OkAaLd0FdK0?t=3 but using dynamic paint, got all of it to work except for the sparks, and placing those manually is not really an option

Comment: Geo Nodes ...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABftdilHiBw  or 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv8B9KxGhW8

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308540/2214

Answer (score 0):

*Unfortunately it's much more complicated than it should be. I can elaborate once you tell me if that's an option for you.*

A possible workaround: Create a particle system sparks that is emitting continously. Place the PS where the laser hits the surface. If you want to randomize the bursts of the sparks some more, you can randomly turn on and off the visibility in render. Note that this might look weird if your spark lifetime is more than a couple of frames.

You could refine that a lot more using animation nodes, by grabbing the position of live particles and placing a custom object where they are relative to the point where the laser hits the surface. This way you have more control when turning them on and off.

Or you could try baking the sparks using physical objects and rigidbody physics. Bake 10 or so, parent them to an object that follows the laser, use animation nodes to only show 3 or 4 at a time and evaluate their f-curves, depending on the current frame and their "birth time".

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. Seems the Particle System does not update the emission distribution relative to the Modifier Stack. God knows when the Blender people will get around fixing/implementing this. Quite the bummer...